# Struggling to convert Objective C selector and target signature to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector

Good Day,

I am trying to convert an Objective C snippet to Swift. I understand the selector can be translated directly by placing it in a string, but I cannot understand the Objective C signature.:

The Objectice C selector (2nd parameter):

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

The target:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
```

My Questions are:
1.Can I simply pass the selector as :

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil);
```

2.Please help me with the singnature of the target function. I am stumped!

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: @jtbandes : Sorry I am unsure what you mean? What should I try?

Comment: Part of your question is "Can I do _x_?" Did you try _x_? What problem are you having?

Comment: Yes I did. I received an error : 'NSInvalidArgumentException ... does not respond to selector image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:'

Comment: Ok... still more information is needed. What class is `self`? Did you implement the `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` method? Please show the relevant parts of your code. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25108888/edit) this information into your question.

Comment: 'self' is a viewcontroller. I didn't implement the method  , I don't know what the signature should be. Thats my main problem

Comment: Have you read [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_27)?

Comment: Hi there, yes I have and I have implemented a few selectors. All with no parameters in the target function. So thats easy for me, I dont know objective C well enough to translate "- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{" into Swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert from an Objective-C method name to Swift the first parameter name in the Objective C method becomes the function name and then the remaining parameters become the parameters of the function.

In your case, the first parameter name is `image`, so the function name in Swift will be `image`.

So,

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

becomes the slightly odd looking -

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError: NSError, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>)       {

}
```

To make things a bit simpler, you an use a different internal parameter name for the error -

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>)       {

}
```

Comment: This is a wonderful solution. I spent hours trying to figure this out before stumbling upon this answer. Is it possible to have a function name that differs from the first argument, and reference that through the Selector() call?

Comment: `UIImage *` and `NSError *` in Objective-C should become `UIImage!` and `NSError!` in swift. What you have is not safe.

Comment: @user102008: You are correct.. keep in mind this question was asked and answered during Swift Beta, a month after it was initially released.