# NSDocument callback method signature

Tags: macos, swift, appkit, nsdocument

I trying to use the `runModalSavePanelForSaveOperation` method on `NSDocument` in Swift, but I get an **"unrecognized selector sent to instance"** exception when the save panel closes. The method call looks like this:

```
self.runModalSavePanelForSaveOperation(.SaveOperation, delegate: self, didSaveSelector: Selector("document:didSave:contextInfo"), contextInfo: nil)
```

And this is what the callback looks like:

```
func document(document: NSDocument, didSave: Bool, contextInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111458/571240) to a similar question it looks like the method signature should be correct. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one colon missing in the selector. It should be

```
Selector("document:didSave:contextInfo:")
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that :)